# mysql update if some values exists otherwise create a new entry

Tags: php, mysql, rating-system

I have a table `rating` with these fields `rate_id, game_id, rating, ip`. Let suppose that these fields has the following values `1,130,5,155.77.66.55`

When a user try to vote for a game, I want with mysql to check if he has already vote for this game so mysql will check if `ip` and `game_id` already exists, if they exists then mysql will update the value of `rating` otherwise will create a new entry.

What is a efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create unique index that covers `ip + game_id`. After that you can use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) statement.

So the total query will be something like

```
INSERT INTO rating (rate_id, game_id, rating, ip) VALUES (1,130,5,'155.77.66.55')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rating = 5
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL allows an on duplicate key update syntax for INSERT. So if you set your key to be game_id, user_id (or whichever way you identify the user) then you can use INSERT...on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE which will do just that:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at REPLACE INTO. Maybe not for this project but for future reference:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT,
>   except that if an old row in the table
>   has the same value as a new row for a
>   PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old
>   row is deleted before the new row is
>   inserted

from: [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
// check to see if exist
$sql = "SELECT ip FROM rating WHERE ip=$ip && game_id={$game_id}";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if(isset($row['ip'])){
  mysql_query("UPDATE HERE");
}else{
  mysql_query("INSERT HERE");
}
```

Comment: What if there will be 2 simultaneous request?

Comment: don't spam your database like that, check @zerkms solution which is the standard way for updating data